# Adding CSS in reactsjs by stylesheet method

Tags: html, css, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to add CSS in my app.js file but it iS not changing the colour of heading h1  Todo Manager

My app.js file:

```
import './App.css';
import Stylesheet from './MyComponents/Stylesheet';

  const App = () => {
    return (
       <div className='App'>
       <Stylesheet primary={true}/>

export default App;
```

`myStyles.css` file

```
.primary {
    color: 'orange';
}
.font-xl {
    font-size: 72px;
}
```

`Stylesheet.js` file:

```
import React from 'react'
import "./myStyles.css"

function Stylesheet(props) {
    let className = props.primary ? 'primary' : ''
    return (
        <div>
            <h1 className={ `${className} font-xl` }>Todo Manager</h1><br /><br /><br />
            
        </div>
    )
}

export default Stylesheet
```

Comment: Have you tried restarting the application? Are there any errors in the console? Are the paths accurate?

Comment: No there is no error in the console

Answer (score 0):

Change the color property from `'orange'` to `orange`, remove the quotation marks.